# Responsive HTML (and CSS)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, breakpoints, adaptive-design

I'm not familiar with responsive websites and would like to start creating a website taking all the screens into account.

Obviously media queries is the way to go but they only concern CSS.

In my current project, I would like to organise the page differently according to the width of the page (being completely device agnostic).
The thing is, on small widths, I would like the HTML layout to change completely so I will have to make the HTML "responsive" as well as it should change according to the website width.

How can I achieve that?
Is there any js library (jQuery if possible but not mandatory) that will "serve" another html page according to the width of the page?

The whole website should be build this way so the script should be more than a gadget, it should be rock solid enough to allow the whole website to rely on it.
And, of course, it should work on any device or screen or browser.

Some would say that I'm looking for adaptive techniques more than responsive ones but I believe it's a mix between those two as the elements will still be responsive in general but between some critical breakpoints, it will indeed adapt and change the html.

I read a lot about different techniques but I can't find something that suits my needs.
Any lead would be appreciated.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is possible with both CSS Media Queries and with JavaScript - but probably not very practical. Try looking at things like the Twitter Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation, both of which offer complete CSS frameworks for design / development

Comment: Try to understand what is CSS mediaquery , You will get an idea of responsive website

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is adaptive delivery. What you want to to is detect the user agent string using a server side language, and then conditionally render your templates according to whether the device is a phone, tablet, or desktop. Realistically, you'll share a lot of code between the screens, but you might have a different navigation layout, or opt to not show more rich features on the smaller screens. This approach not only saves a bunch of hide/show code, but saves a lot of overhead on smaller screens where you would otherwise be loading stuff that would be hidden the entire time anyway.

Comment: This is exactly what I want (but being device agnostic as I don't want to specify any device anywhere). But I'm still looking at something that does that without finding it yet. If I'm not wrong the user-agent will segregate the browser or the device, not the width and this is what I need. I found "response.js" but it doesn't switch the whole html tag, it just allows to change some div tags and src's.

Comment: That's a tough one. If you wanna get really intense with it, you can set up client side views using something like Backbone or Angular and then use window resize events to trigger alternate content loads.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot with CSS and media queries to alter your page layout ("completly") depending on device and screen width. If I were you I would dig a little deeper through the possibilities these techniques can offer.

If you are positive this is not enough. I would look into [Redirects and User-Agent Detection](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/redirects) to redirect your users to a different page depending on the user-agent.

If you are looking for a full framework that can handle both what you need (redirecting and dynamic content depending on user-agent or width) and a whole lot more, you should look into [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

You CAN of course do some DOM manipulation with pure JS depending on your criteria, but as your project gets bigger you might be in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you could use an existing CSS framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to achieve a responsive design across your various target browser widths and device types?

Bootstrap in particular will let you specify different layouts depending on the device width where the page is being rendered. [More information here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) - adjust your browser width to see it in action.

If, after evaluating an existing framework, you're still determined to develop your own you can perhaps at least use the techniques in Bootstrap or another framework as a starting point for your own.

Comment: I read the Bootstrap doc and I get the responsive thing and the toolbox concept but I still don't see how I can vary my HTML according to the width of the window.

Comment: I guess the point of Bootstrap is to abstract away the need for you to worry about producing different Html depending on the viewport/browser width your users are using. And for instances where you need to be more explicit about what gets shown at a particular width then you can resort to the responsive CSS utility classes (see more info link above).

Comment: What seems to remain misunderstood is that I'm not looking for a website to look only good at different widths, I want it to look completely different in structure at different widths WHILE being responsive between some crucial breakpoints. So this is not about hiding/showing/moving some elements from a size to another to fit the space, it's about changing the whole HTML between two sizes and bring a completely different experience. I thought we can change the whole HTML according to the size but it seems that it's not possible. I could use Bootstrap if only it fitted my needs but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

try [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Bootstrap makes front-end web development faster and easier. It's made for folks of all skill levels, devices of all shapes, and projects of all sizes.

Comment: Sorry but this is a commercial, not an answer to my question.

Comment: Code licensed under MIT

Comment: What I mean by commercial is not the fact that you pay for it but the fact that you gave me an answer that is just a generic catch phrase, not an answer to my question. Your answer would be the same for any question with the word "responsive" or "grid" in it. And thank you for the payback by the way... You didn't downvote because my question is not relevant but because I said that yours is.

Comment: open this page  (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)  and  resize your page.and see what bootstrap change the layout  dynamiv with screen size. it make the page  fit and look godd in every screen

Comment: This is way more helpful, thank you. Now, is it me or the only layout that changes there is the css? For what I see, the HTML remains the same. If there is a way to change the html content completely according to the width, I'm in but I read the doc and didn't find this feature. For what I see it is 100% responsive and 0% adaptive. Am I wrong?

Comment: same item is hidden in small screen like right panel  , menu also became button menu

Comment: Thank you. Hide a div and show another is not an option for me as I would end up with too many tags to hide or to show. This is a good solution for occasional hiding/showing but not for a complete change of structure. And this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is sufficient to your project, but you can to some extent use CSS to control what markup you would like to show or hide on smaller or larger devices. For example:

```
    <div class="mobile-only">
      <p>This content will only be visible on small screens such as mobile devices</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tablet-up">
      <p>This content will only be visible in tablet and larger devices</p>
    </div>

    /* media query for small screens, such as mobile devices */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .tablet-up {
        display: none !important;
      }
    }

    /* media query for tablet and larger devices*/
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .mobile-only {
        display: none !important;
      }
    }
```

But be sure that you do not use this technique if you have a really big project, you might be ending up choking performance.